# Add image to item (spinner)

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

Hi I am an amateur in android .I would like to add images to my spinner's item. Unfortunately, I dont know how to do it . 
Below is my xml file and MainActivity.
Thanks for reading.

**XML FILE**

```
    <resources>
    <string-array name="walutyarrajwoskie">
    <item>ALL</item>
    <item>AMD</item>
    <item>AZN</item>
    <item>BYR</item>
    <item>BAM</item>
    <item>BGN</item>
    </string-array>
    </resources>
```

**MAINACTIVITY**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    editText_waluty= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_waluty);
    spinner_from =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
    spinner_to =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2_to);
    textview_to= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2_to);
    button_konwertuj= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_konwertuj);






    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.**walutyarrajwoskie**, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spinner_from.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner_to.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You should define you own custom adapter. there are lot's of tutorial about this. here is an example:  https://github.com/dlukashev/android-phone-number-with-flags

Comment: thanks for help Amir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use custom Spinner

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_spinner_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /><!--Make sure image is present in Drawable folder-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package example.abhiandriod.customspinnerexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{


    String[] countryNames={"India","China","Australia","Portugle","America","New Zealand"};
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.india, R.drawable.china, R.drawable.australia, R.drawable.portugle, R.drawable.america, R.drawable.new_zealand};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flags,countryNames);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }


    //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), countryNames[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package example.abhiandriod.customspinnerexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] countryNames) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.countryNames = countryNames;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(countryNames[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

[Source from this website](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html)